# after Entering npm install -g create-react-app the below message comes up , how to fix that?

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd

For both react js and react native this message appear!
Please spend time and solve my big problem

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 17s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

after entering the npm audit:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK

npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.

npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only

npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Real Acc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-25T14_34_14_987Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try to update your `node` version

Comment: @KJ hey man! haha Lol yes of course... I edited

Comment: @PhucNguyen I did...even I reinstalled my windows!

Comment: Before you reinstalled windows(?!) did you try following the instructions given in the error message? `Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only`

Comment: @DanielBeck Hi sir... no  I did not  but then?